# Binding to event property is disallowed

Tags: angular

How to resolve this error, no idea where to debug?

```
ERROR Error: Binding to event property 'onlyPicture' is disallowed for security reasons, please 
use (lyPicture)=...
If 'onlyPicture' is a directive input, make sure the directive is imported by the current 
module
```

Is it a major issue or something can we ignore this error?

Comment: It look like event's name beginning with "on" are not allowed. Did you try with something else ? like `pictureOnly` for example ?

Comment: Yeah i have seen the same kind of issue in stackoverflow too (beginning with ON). But am not using anything like that, also in my project "pictureOnly" keyword is not there...! this is something else !